# Angular JS - ng-repeat is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried to make an example similar to the examples in https://angularjs.org/

Here is the JS fiddle I have created.

Can some one help. What is wrong in this?

HTML is..

```
<h2>
To Do
</h2>
<div ng-controller="ToDoListController as todoList">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
      {{todo.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and JS part is

```
angular.module('todoApp',[]).controller('ToDoListController', 
function(){
var todoList = this;
    todoList.todos = [
      {text:'learn angular', done:true},
      {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];
});
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/bkozoe8L/#&togetherjs=wjdvVubPni) for JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your fiddle. There were two issues

1. Body tag should be enclosed in <>
2. Angular js was not being used

Comment: So you mean I need to add <body ng-app="todoApp"> as body tag?

Comment: @ketan Yes, else it will just show `body ng-app="todoApp"` as text

Comment: thanks for that. But I added Angular JS as an external js in fiddle. Is there any other way to add this?

Comment: Goto javascript settings>Framework and Extensions>Angular 1.4.8 >Load type>No Wrap in head

Comment: Great.. Learn new thing.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**CONTROLLER**

```
angular.module('todoApp',[]).controller('ToDoListController',function(){
$scope.todoList = [];
$scope.todoList = [
  {text:'learn angular', done:true},
  {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp" >
<h2>
 To Do
</h2>
<div ng-controller="ToDoListController">
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList">
      {{todo.text}}
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not we required todo with text? why?

Comment: you can use todo.text, so you will get only text value instead off whole object

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the property in this manner:

```
{{todo["text"]}}
```

I made the update to your fiddle.